# How to multiply the elements of a list diagonally?

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart

```
List a = [2,3,4];
List b = [5,6,7];
```

I want to print 2x7, 3x6, and 4x5

Comment: does your lists can have different lengths?

Comment: They have the same length

Answer (score 0):

```
b = b.reversed.toList();
for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
{
  print(a[i] * b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
final a = [2, 3, 4];
final b = [5, 6, 7];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    final result = a[i] * b[a.length - i - 1];

    print('${a[i]} * ${b[a.length - i - 1]} = $result');
}
```